# How can I solve congruences similar to $24x \equiv 3 \pmod 5 $

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How can I solve congruences similar to $$24x \equiv 3 \pmod 5 $$

I know this is pretty straightforward, I am just drawing a blank, so I can't get to the final steps of my proof.

Comment: NEVERMIND! HAHA MY BAD

Comment: Write up your solution as an answer. This way we can check whether your reasoning is correct and the question does not remain unanswered :)

Comment: Perhaps someone should mention 24=25-1.

Answer (score 2):

First, notice that since 5 is prime, each non-zero value will have an inverse and thus you could multiply each side by the inverse of 24 which in this case is 4.  Thus,  $$x \equiv 2 \pmod 5 $$ is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$24\times 5\equiv0\mod 5$, which means if $x$ is a solution, $x+5$ is also a solution. So you only need to check a few values of $x$.